# Monthwise defaulterlist of students

Tags: sql-server

Table name: student

```
Stu_id  Stu_Name    
1       ani 
2       sudipta 
3       debayan 
4       achinto 
5       dipankar
```

Table name: trans

```
stu_id   mon    amount
1        JANU   500
1        FEB    600
1        APR    500
3       JANU    600
3        MAR    700
```

result will be below

```
STU_ID    STU_NAME   Defaulter month
1         ani           MAR,MAY,JUNE,JULY,AUG,SEP,OCT,NOV,DEC
2         SUDIPTA       JANU.FEB,MAR,APR,MAY,JUNE,JULY,AUG,SEP,OCT,NOV,DEC
3         debayan       FEB,APR,MAY,JUNE,JULY,AUG,SEP,OCT,NOV,DEC
4         achinto       JANU.FEB,MAR,APR,MAY,JUNE,JULY,AUG,SEP,OCT,NOV,DEC
5         dipankar      JANU.FEB,MAR,APR,MAY,JUNE,JULY,AUG,SEP,OCT,NOV,DEC
```

Comment: why not store the mon column as a number, so at the tme of entry
u will store month number, and for taking out the record,
u can then check for missing numbers from 1 to 12 in a simple for loop

Comment: Please, write more in detail what you need.

Comment: i have two gtables 1) student and 2) is trans, now trans store the transaction or fees collection record through out the year , now i need the list of defaulter, who does not pay .

Comment: usman, using loops it will take 5 min from the front end using vb.